# How to create a TableView with the rows displaying a value from an SQLite database in Titanium Studio?

Tags: database, sqlite, titanium

I'm trying to create an app using **Titanium Studio** that will display information from an SQLite database.
To make things simpler, lets say my database have the following columns:
**Last Name, Given Name, Age, Race & Religion**

I currently have a basic framework for the app, which consists of multiple tabs.
In one of the tabs (which corresponds to a particular window), I would like to have a TableView that displays only **Last Name, Given Name & Age** in each row.

How do I do that?
Appreciate all the help I can get!

Thanks!

Comment: first of all, let us know if you can create database or not, make some db entries or not, retrieve database from it or not. Could you create TableView?

Comment: Hey! I've created a database using SQLite, and using that programme i've input some data into that database. I was then able to install the database using the install database method.

Comment: Also, i was able to create the tableview, just that I don't know how to show the values from the database in the TableViewRows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Have you looked at this?](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Working_with_a_SQLite_Database)

So once you get the rows from the database, just create rows for your tableview. Here is a start:

```
// Fetch the db and execute a select from your person table
var db = Ti.Database.open('mydb');
var rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM person');

var persons = [];
while (rows.isValidRow())
{
    persons.push({title : + rows.fieldByName('Last Name'));
    rows.next();
};
rows.close();

var yourTable = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    data: persons // Set the rows to the table
});

// Dont forget to close the db
db.close();
```

[Use this as a reference to style your table rows more effectively.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/TableViews)